# Animate onclick event's display:none

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a div that is being hidden by a button's onclick event. When the button is clicked, and the div goes to "display: none", the div below instantly moves 'up' in its place. Is there any way to use a CSS3 transition to ease this action?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you tried (so we don't do the same mistake hahah)

Comment: Roko, unfortunately, all I've tried was using a basic CSS3 transition on the div, like you would with a :hover selector... That didn't seem to work.

Comment: The `display` property is not transition-able/animate-able, for the simple reason that it is “binary” – and element is either shown, or it is not; there is nothing “in between”.

Answer (score 0):

When using CSS3 transition, all you need to do is change the style of the transition set. Below I have a demo that will allow you to have multiple elements use the transition.

```js
function ClickEvents(){
  //Get toggle Elements By Class Name
var Boxes=document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
//For each element found
    for(var i=0; i<Boxes.length; i++){
//Set the event listener
Boxes[i].addEventListener('click',Transition,false);    
    }
}
function Transition(){
//(This) the element clicked/used to call the function
    this.style.height='0px';
}
//Set onclick events.
window.onload=ClickEvents;
```

```css
.toggle{
cursor:pointer;
height:150px;
width:150px;
overflow:hidden;
transition : height 550ms;
}
#Box1{background:blue;}
#Box2{background:red;}
```

```html
<div id="Box1" class="toggle">Click Me</div>
<div id="Box2" class="toggle">Click Me</div>
```

> **Edit:** I have created another example for using a button to trigger the toggle.
>
> *Remember, demos/examples are for you to expand on.* **[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/46fdhm1h/)**

If you have any questions, please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!